# UISwitch unresponsive in iOS map callout

Tags: ios, swift4, mkannotation, uiswitch

I have the following code which places a switch in the left accessory view of an annotation's callout, but the switch doesn't change when I tap it

```
let switchDemo = UISwitch()
switchDemo.isOn = true
switchDemo.isEnabled = true;
switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false)
switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = switchDemo
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

nvm you just have to hold it down slightly longer